# C++ ->Trying to read a line of text word by word. How to make a pointer equivalent of the current 2 dimensional array used to store the input

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Wrote this program to read a user input, word by word

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
int i=0;
    char input[50][50];

    cout<<"Enter input: ";
    cin>>input[i];

    while(strcmp("q",input[i]))
    {
        i++;
        cin>>input[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;

    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        cout<<input[j]<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

Currently using a two-dimensional character array to store the input. I'm not that good with pointers since i just read about those.

Is there a pointer equivalent of `char input[50][50]`?
I know this range of [50] is a bad idea. Using pointers should solve it right?

I tried doing this-> `char* input= new char[50]` , but i guess this is the wrong way? Does `char* input= new char[50]` create a pointer to array of strings or a pointer to array of characters?

Please keep it simple. just started with arrays.

Comment: why would you want a pointer instead of `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible to do that. Like i said, i just started with pointers so just for practice .

Comment: You need a pointer pointing to array of length 2500 and do index computation by hand. i.e. to get element on `[i,j]` you need to do `i * 50 + j`. Or vice versa if you want column major layout. I hope it is clear why multiplication needed.

Comment: Oh . I hoped there's a way to store it like `{ "string1", "string2", "string3"}` by creating a pointer to array of strings .

Comment: whatever the exercise is, I recommend you to forget about it, because in modern C++ raw pointers are very rare. I recommend you learning to use standard library first, because it will give more insights on what C++ design is. It is possible to do that, but you will need array of pointers and allocate memory for each pointer (but it is very old, C way of doing things).

Comment: Sure! Will follow the advice

Answer (score 0):

`char* input= new input[50];` is wrong;

`char * input = new char[50];` is correct.

its creates a dynamic 1D array of characters. It is not the array of pointers. If you want to create an 2D array of characters

here is the syntax

```
char * arr = new char*[rows]; //creates an 1D array of character pointers
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
arr[i]=new char[columns]; //Creates Array for every Row, to make it 2D array
```

You can assume 2D character array as a 1D string array, because string is also a character array.
More I would suggest you to use strings you can easily manipulate a string.

Comment: Oops! Wrote `new input[50]` by mistake. I'll make the edits in my question . Does this create a pointer to array of strings or a pointer to arrays of character? 
And yes i can do it easily by storing the entire thing in a string but i just want to give it a try using pointers

Comment: String and character arrays are same for visualization but different in codes and functions.